# The robot is not selecting each element of the combobox (VBA/Excel/Webscraping)

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, web-scraping

I am doing simple webscraping using VBA/Excel and the robot is not working to select each element of the combobox to do the extraction.

Part of the Code bellow:

```
Set evtprod = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evtprod.initEvent "change", True, False

Set lstprod = IE.Document.getElementById(var2)

Set contr = IE.Document.getElementById(var2)
contrn = contr.Length

While iprod < contrn

    lstprod.selectedIndex = iprod
    lstprod.dispatchEvent evtprod

    Sleep 300

    Do
        DoEvents
        Sleep 300
    Loop While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("plan2").Cells(iLineprod, 2) = IE.Document.All.Item("ddlprod").Item(iprod).Value

  Set divs = IE.Document.getElementById("bxcategory")
  value = divs.innertext

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("plan2").Cells(iLineprod, 5) = Value

    iprod = iprod + 1
    iLineprod = iLineprod + 1

Wend
```

I believe that is something wrong with the code "lstprod.selectedIndex = iprod", because when I manually change iprod for instance by the number 2, "lstprod.selectedIndex = 2" it selects the second element of the combox, but it is not interating through. Or maybe the problem is with "lstprod.dispatchEvent evtprod".

Any idea about how to figure out that?

Thanks is advance

Comment: What's the website you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the approach I took.

1) Create a GET request to pull the page data.

2) Stored the page data into a temp HTML file.

3) Used element selectors to find the dropdown's ID, then pulled all the Option tags that are part of that ID.

For the below solution to work, add a reference to `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60` first, otherwise you will run into issues running the code.

I wasn't sure if you wanted to see the visible value (InnerText) e.g.`Alphaville` or the underlying value `0106` so I showed how to display both.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getWebData()
On Error GoTo errhand:
    Dim getReq          As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60 'Add a reference!
    Dim doc             As Object: Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim Elements        As Object
    Dim Element         As Object

    With getReq
        .Open "GET", "www.somewebsite.com" 'removed actual site URL
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
        .send
        .waitForResponse 2
    End With
    If getReq.Status = 200 Then 'if successful
        doc.body.innerHTML = getReq.responseText
        Set Elements = doc.getElementById("campusDropDownList").getElementsByTagName("option")
        For Each Element In Elements
            Debug.Print Element.Value, Element.innerText
        Next
    End If
    Exit Sub
errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Description, Err.Number
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ryan Thanks for the answer but it looks like the changed the website then my code doens t work anymore. Is that possible to use your code above to extract the data?

Comment: If someone decides to change their website significantly, then yes this wouldn't work. However, that's true of any approach. Does the code work now?

Comment: It is not working at the moment, but your help was really good. thanks

Comment: Working fine for me...what error(s) are you receiving? You aren't seeing anything in the Immediate Window?

Comment: It is not giving me error message, it is giving me nothing. I am sorry a begginer user of vba and webscraping that is the reason that I am quite lost here

Comment: Change `Debug.Print Element.Value, Element.innerText` to `MsgBox (Element.InnerText)`. Do you see a message box now?